# Regular expression return escaped char

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Is it possible to escape a set of chars with a regex.

An example:

```
Input: name!surname
Output: name\!surname
```

The idea is to escape all the non alphanumeric chars, I know how to write a regex to find them but really struggle to escape.

Using Oracle's SQL with `REGEXP_REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('name!surname?', '[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]', '#') from sys.dual;
```

The output would look as follow `name#surname#` but I would like to know if it is possible to get something like `name\!surname\?`.

I need to escape all the non alphanumeric chars for Oracle Text to parse a query.

I can't use {} for multi-escaping since it doesn't work with the wildcard %.

Comment: Done. Check. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double backslash before `\1` as the third argument, together with `[^[:alnum:]]` posix ( the `[:space:]` posix just before the closing bracket and parentheses is due to get rid of backslash replacing with spaces ):

```
select regexp_replace('name!surname','([^[:alnum:][:space:]])','\\\1') 
  from dual
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4484bf605367ef4c4a8515af53cd9737)</kbd>

Comment: How to exclude `{}` from the regex?

Comment: if you mean to extract `name\{}surname` as a result, adding a closing curly brace `}` after `[:space:]` posix such as `'([^[:alnum:][:space:]}])'` should be enough @dmak2709

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the character group you are trying to match in a capturing group and then use `\\\1` as the replacement. `\\` is an escaped backslash and `\1` will insert the contents of the first capturing group:

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace('name! surname?', '([^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]:])', '\\\1')
       AS replacement
from sys.dual;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | REPLACEMENT     |
> | :-------------- |
> | name\!surname\? |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=090b02095e49f82f31d294c6ea4daebd)*

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('name!surname','([[:punct:]])','\\\1') from dual
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/QVZUD56960), result:

[image]

The pattern is `([[:punct:]])`, a single capturing group that matches a single punctuation or symbol char. The replacement is a backslash + the group value.

Note that `\` in the replacement pattern is a special character, it is used to introduce *placeholders*, *replacement backreferences*, hence, it should be escaped itself to produce a literal backslash in the resulting string.